# Count numbers in row together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my database named `club`. In `club` there's a row called `speler_id` with this `speler_id` i can get the value of the `speler_id`. I want to count the values together (because a user has more than 1 `speler_id`) this is the code:

```
$punten = 0;

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `club` WHERE `user_id`=" . $userid ." ";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result2)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=" . $row2['speler_id'] . " ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());   
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
    $punten += $row['xb_end_range'];
    echo $punten;
}
```

but when I execute this, it gives me all the values not the value total.

Sorry for using mySQL will update it to PDO or mySQLi soon.

---

EDIT

I found the answer:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(xb_end_range) AS punten
    FROM club AS c
    JOIN players_db AS p ON c.speler_id = p.id
    WHERE c.user_id = $userid";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$punten = $row['punten'];

echo number_format("$punten")
```

Comment: It's a bit vague what you want, but you're looking (probably) for something like this: `"SELECT SUM(xb_end_range) AS total FROM players_db WHERE id=" .... `

Comment: If you just want to see the final total, put `echo $punten` after the end of the loop.

Comment: I think you're confusing rows with columns. Rows don't have names, `speler_id` is the name of a column. What do you mean by "with this `speler_id` I can get the value of the `speler_id`"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, try to avoid doing queries inside a loop. Instead, join the tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(xb_end_range) AS punten
    FROM club AS c
    JOIN players_db AS p ON c.speler_id = p.id
    WHERE c.user_id = $userid";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$punten = $row['punten'];
echo $punten;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you are manually joining the `club` table to the `players_db` table, but it would be far more efficient, both in code and in running time, to let the DB do it for you.  In the second place, you are performing a manual aggregation (or attempting to do), which also would be more efficiently performed by the database.  Overall, it looks like you want to execute a query something like this:

```
select ifnull(sum(p.xb_end_range), 0) as punten
from
  club c
  join players_db p on p.id = c.speler_id
where c.user_id = 'the-user-id'
```

That will return exactly one row with what I take to be the desired sum as as the value of the only column, "punten".

Comment: It will never return 0 rows. If there are no matches, it will still return a row with `punten = NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar, you're quite right.  I have corrected my commentary, and furthermore updated the query to return `0` instead of `NULL` in the case of no matching rows.